# loading information from a file into a window

Tags: c#

I have the following form.  The first button opens a text file and displays the file in the rich text box in the form.  The second button opens another window.  What I want is for that window to be pre-populated with the data that is in that text file...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HomeInventory2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

The form that needs to be populated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HomeInventory2.Domain;
using HomeInventory2.Business;

namespace HomeInventory2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateInventory create = new CreateInventory();
            create.ItemAmount = textBoxAmount.Text;
            create.ItemCategory = textBoxCategories.Text;
            create.ItemProperties = textBoxValue.Text;
            create.ItemValue = textBoxValue.Text;

            InventoryMngr invtryMngr = new InventoryMngr();
            invtryMngr.Create(create);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to keep out the clutter in your code, like the Using / Namespace statements and empty events. Try to only post relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new constructor which takes a `string` overload. When you open the new `Form`, pass in the text date and fill the textbox.

```
//in the new form that opens up
public Form1(string prepopulated)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myRichTextbox.Text = prepopulated;
}
```

And call it from your click event like this:

```
//in the first form
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Run(new Form1(richTextBox1.Text));
}
```

If your content is more complicated than a simple text file, you can use [RichTextBox.Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx) instead and pass that instead of the string. Change the overload to

```
Form1(FlowDocument prepopulated)
```

and call it like this

```
Application.Run(new Form1(richTextBox1.Document));
```